# Alignment of buttons on page in accordance with above text

Tags: html, css, bigcommerce

[Add to Cart alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjeC0.jpg)

***See Above Image***

I'm trying to get an 'Add to Cart' button to align with the others in the same row of a page. I'm currently only aware of doing this one of two ways:

1. Adding whitespace between one of the elements to ensure proper alignment
2. Setting a fixed height to each product element

The problem is that when the text becomes longer and begins to wrap (as displayed in the image), the buttons become vertically misaligned on the page.

Which would be the better choice in this situation, and how might I go about getting started in completing that task?

HTML Markup:

```css
    .card-title {
        font-size: 1rem;
        margin: 0 0 1rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .card {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        min-width: 0;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        background-color: $fff;
        background-clip: border-box;
        border: 1px solid;
        border-radius: 0.25rem;
    }
```

```html
    <article class="card ">
    <figure class="card-figure">
        <div class="sale-badge animated bounceIn"><span>Sale</span></div>
        <a href="/olio-trevi-extra-virgin-olive-oil-500ml/" tabindex="0">
            <div class="card-img-container">
                <img class="card-image lazyautosizes lazyloaded" data-sizes="auto" src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-zji14g4v8/images/stencil/180x180/products/949/1182/trevi__64427__36013.1544206184.jpg?c=2" data-src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-zji14g4v8/images/stencil/180x180/products/949/1182/trevi__64427__36013.1544206184.jpg?c=2" alt="Olio Trevi Extra Virgin Olive Oil - 500ml" title="Olio Trevi Extra Virgin Olive Oil - 500ml" width="180" height="180" sizes="130px">
            </div>
        </a>
        <figcaption class="card-figcaption">
            <div class="card-figcaption-body">
                <a href="#" class="button button--primary button--icon quickview" data-product-id="949" data-title="Quick view" tabindex="0">
                    <i class="icon">
                        <svg>
                            <use xlink:href="#icon-eye"></use>
                        </svg>
                    </i>
                </a>
                <a href="/wishlist.php?action=add&amp;product_id=949" class="button button--primary button--icon wishlist" data-title="Add to Wish List" tabindex="0">
                    <i class="icon">
                        <svg>
                            <use xlink:href="#icon-heart"></use>
                        </svg>
                    </i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">
            <a href="/olio-trevi-extra-virgin-olive-oil-500ml/" tabindex="0">Olio Trevi Extra Virgin Olive Oil - 500ml</a>
        </h4>
        <p data-test-info-type="summary">This fresh, fruity, and intensely green Umbrian olive oil has been produced in the Trevi hillsides for 2,000 years. The production techniques are not …</p>
        <p class="card-text" data-test-info-type="productRating">
            <span class="rating--small">
                <span class="icon icon--ratingEmpty">
                    <svg>
                        <use xlink:href="#icon-star"></use>
                    </svg>
                </span>
                <span class="icon icon--ratingEmpty">
                    <svg>
                        <use xlink:href="#icon-star"></use>
                    </svg>
                </span>
                <span class="icon icon--ratingEmpty">
                    <svg>
                        <use xlink:href="#icon-star"></use>
                    </svg>
                </span>
                <span class="icon icon--ratingEmpty">
                    <svg>
                        <use xlink:href="#icon-star"></use>
                    </svg>
                </span>
                <span class="icon icon--ratingEmpty">
                    <svg>
                        <use xlink:href="#icon-star"></use>
                    </svg>
                </span>
                <!-- snippet location product_rating -->
            </span>
        </p>
        <div class="card-text" data-test-info-type="price">
            <div class="price-section non-sale-price---withoutTax price-section--withoutTax ">
                <span class="price-was-label">Was:</span>
                <span data-product-non-sale-price-without-tax="" class="price price--rrp"> $29.99</span>
            </div>
            <div class="price-section">
                <span class="price-now-label">
                Now:
                </span>
                <span data-product-price-without-tax="" class="price price--withoutTax"> $25.99</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="/olio-trevi-extra-virgin-olive-oil-500ml/" class="button button--primary button--cartAction" data-product-id="949" tabindex="0">Choose Options</a>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Without adding any markup you are decreasing your chances of getting a proper answer.

Comment: Thank you, I will add that information.

Comment: Hi, the answer below to change the images to be the same size is the simplest solution on the BigCommerce platform. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54189553/4017634

Answer (score 2):

Resizing the product images to have uniform height would fix alignment without using any CSS.

Alternatively, setting a min-height equal to the tallest image on all images should align all of the items.

Comment: This unfortunately did not fix the issue, all elements remained in their original positions after setting min-height and height.

Answer (score 1):

Adding whitespace is not a sound solution. Setting the same fixed height would work, you have the option of playing with "margin", "padding" and "line-height" to achieve the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

I would try this with flexbox using the align items stretch (min/max height for products) and bottom align your add to cart link.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

Better to set fixed height for block before button or make position for button related to main block use css option "position" for product block as "relative" and for button as "absolute" and set it to bottom (bottom: 0;). You can read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you assign your cards a specific height, divide the contents of the card into 3 parts: image / content / button (add to car), assign the following properties to the parent container of these 3 elements:

```
.card-wrapp {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
```

and then you would have to assign a specific size to the title, since this can become extremely long, you could add:

```
.card__title {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```